# Sending email via Amazon SES SMTP error

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to send email via Amazon SES new SMTP service using .NET's built-in `SmtpClient`

Code:

```
    var emailClient = new SmtpClient("email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", 465);
                    emailClient.EnableSsl = true;
....
emailClient.Send(message);
```

I get an exception:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection:
>   net_io_connectionclosed

Google says this error means that I can't reach SMTP server.
They require TLS which I beleive achieved by "EnableSsl" property.

Anybody know how I need to tweak my code to make it work?

**EDIT:**

I guess I will close this question. No, it's not possible to do what I want with SmtpClient

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=302112&#302112

Comment: Not directly answering the question, but you can download AWSSDK.dll and use their own API, it's really incredibly easy and you don't need to worry about SMTP, compatibility, ISPs, etc.

Comment: Thats what I'm using right now. But I wanted to do SMTP since they released it recently. That way I don't have to deal with AWSSDK

Comment: Are you supplying your SES username and password anywhere?

Comment: yes, those are in config file. But it errors out in 30 sec or so, it tells me something with connectivity

Comment: and here i was like, "Oh i'll have this up and running with SMTP in no time. Way quicker than AWSSDK!"

Comment: I ended up buying aspnetMail component. Best of all worlds IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm that it works with STARTTLS and port 587.

Hope that helps

Comment: :( I've just tested now and only 2587 works with default SmtpClient. Well, at least it works after hour of trying different ports...

Comment: Your link is broken. You should replace it or remove it

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to do this by specifying port 587.

```
<system.net>
   <mailSettings>
     <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
       <network enableSsl="true" port="587" host="email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" password="[password]" userName="[username]"/>
     </smtp>
   </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

With that as the configuration, you can use the SmtpClient as you normally would

```
var client = new SmtpClient();
var message = new MailMessage(fromemail, recipient, subject, body);
client.Send(message);
```

Comment: I guess it was just added. Can you post link to Amazon SES documentation where they confirm support to port 587?

Comment: I have a situation were the same configuration works on windows 7 but not on windows xp. Any idea why?

Comment: @katit: This is the official announcement: http://aws.amazon.com/de/about-aws/newsletters/2012/03/15/March2012/
Check out the blog post in my answer for more information

Answer (score 5):

According to Amazon - it is not supported as we used to.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=302112&#302112

> The .NET email TLS libraries only support STARTTLS which SES does not
>   support today. We support what is called "TLS Wrapper" or SMTPS
>   authentication.   I can understand how this would be frustrating, but
>   you can use OpenSSL as a workaround and tunnel through that software
>   running on your computer to use .NET to program against our SMTP
>   endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

As masterfu mentions in his blog post, Amazon SES started supporting STARTTLS in March of 2012.

Below is the code that I used to get SMTP working with Amazon.

```
  string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSMTPUser"];
  string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSMTPPass"];

  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
  smtp.Host = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
  smtp.Port = 587;
  smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
  smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
  smtp.EnableSsl = true;

  smtp.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 3):

Now SES supports STARTTTLS:

> Outgoing server (SMTP)—25, 587, or 2587 (to connect using STARTTLS),
>   or 465 or 2465 (to connect using TLS Wrapper).

Pruf link: http://s3.amazonaws.com/awsdocs/ses/latest/ses-dg.pdf

Answer (score 1):

For Anyone who wants to send with normal .Net SMTPClient. It is possible as you just need a wrapper.

Here's a link with all the info:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/SMTP.Client.html

Install the tunneling software and configure as the describe in the link then its as simple as :

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
sc.Host = host;
sc.Port = port;
sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
sc.Send(mm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set defaultCredentials="false" in web.config?

Comment: I am very curious as to what you mean or why this would work: you're assuming that an ASP.NET web app is being developed I guess, but why would some credentials setting in web.config affect an SMTP connection?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion if I misunderstood the meaning of the "config file", which I assumed was the Web.config with associated SMTP settings. When I have used (.NET) SMTP and needed to supply a username and password, I did so in the <smtp> section. If I did not set the defaultCredettials=false, the connection would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try using port no. 2587, other port 25, 425, 587 dint work for my case.